# in rails, how would I output the name of the view file being used based upon a global setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to set a global variable such as SHOW_VIEW_FILES that when set to true, will output `__FILE__` at the top of the view file (basically so we can see which files are used quickly rather than tracing code)? Was thinking that probably there is a string that gets appended to for view output and could just add it to the top there.

Or automatically inject a call to a method at the top of each view file? Is something like this already in existence - I think it should be like a one-liner.

Any ideas on how to get this done? Even better would be a way to suppress the normal output and output a tree structure (obviously more than a one-liner).

thx in advance